# Performance improvement of WCF data transfer to client

Tags: wcf

We are using a WCF service. We are trying to return data of size 3MB to our client/application from WCF.

When we do in locally its just taking 2 seconds. We have hosted the service on a server and when we tried accessing it in the same location its just 2 seconds. But when we try to access it from other geographic region or location it is taking around 40 seconds.

We have tried using Mtom and streamed response but we did not have any improvement. It would be of great help if anyone can let us know a means to improve the performance when accessing it from different region?

Comment: Which binding are you using?

Comment: Which `transferMode` are you using with Mtom?

Comment: We are using basic http binding. We have tried using transfer mode as text as well as Mtom. But the response time seems to be same with 3MB data.